# How to handle multiple devices logins with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, unity-game-engine, amazon-cognito

I'm new to Amazon web services in general. I don't understand how does Cognito work with Facebook on multiple devices. Is it possible to have same data on multiple devices? How do I set that up in Unity? Is there a document about this?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito is intended to work seamlessly on multiple devices with Facebook. When you pass the Facebook access token to Cognito, you get an identityId. This id is constant for the facebook user across devices, so any data stored against this id is intended to be accessible across devices.

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) should be a good starting point for you.